# Glitchy-Freezing - Not smooth animation on scroll - using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

I'm working on [this experiment](http://codepen.io/dghez/pen/qEjraR) and I have a problem. 
 I was working on Chrome (40) & Windows and everything works like a charm, than I took my mac with Chrome (41dev) and the transition isn't as smooth as the one on Windows.  
 I really can't realize why it happens. 
Maybe because I'm new in such kind of animation.

### EDIT:

I've put the animation inside requestAnimationFrame but anything changed.

### EDIT 2 :

I added a condition to try to fire the animation ONCE, and it fired right, but in mac is still not smooth, a little glitchy 
Thats my js: ( better check that on codepen )

```
function move(){
 var title = $('h1');
 title
    .css({
      transform: "translate3d(0px,0px, 0px)",
      WebkitTransform: "translate3d(0px,0px, 0px)",
      MozTransform: "translate3d(0px,0px, 0px)",
      msTransform: "translate3d(0px,0px, 0px)"});
}
function scrolling(lastScrollTop){
  var vh =$(window).height();
  vh = vh - 300;
  var title = $("h1");
  var posTitle = $("h1").offset().top;
  var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
  var leftTitle = $("h1").offset().left;
  var moveY = -(posTitle - 300);
  var moveX = -(leftTitle - 150);
  var fired = false;
  /* SCROLL DOWN*/
   if (scrolled > lastScrollTop && scrolled < vh){
     if( $('html,body').is(':not(:animated)') && fired == false ){
      fired = true;
      $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop : vh}, 700, function(){fired = false});
      console.log("triggerato scende");
      move();
      title.removeClass("opening");
     }     
   }
    /* SCROLL UP*/
    else{
     if(scrolled < vh){if( $('html,body').is(':not(:animated)') ){
       fired = true;
        $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop : 0}, 700, function(){fired = false});
        console.log("triggerato su");
         title
         .css({
          transform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px, 0px) scale3d(1.33,1.33,1)", 
          WebkitTransform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px, 0px) scale3d(1.33,1.33,1)", 
          MozTransform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px, 0px) scale3d(1.33,1.33,1)", 
          msTransform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px, 0px) scale3d(1.33,1.33,1)" });
        title.addClass("opening");
      }       
     }
   }   
   lastScrollTop = scrolled;
  return lastScrollTop;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  var vh =$(window).height();
  vh = vh - 300;
  var title = $("h1");
  var posTitle = title.offset().top;
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var scrolled;
  var leftTitle = title.offset().left;
  var moveY = -(posTitle - 300);
  var moveX = -(leftTitle - 150);
  $(title)
    .css({
      transform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px, 0px) scale3d(1.33,1.33,1)", 
      WebkitTransform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px, 0px) scale3d(1.33,1.33,1)", 
      MozTransform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px, 0px) scale3d(1.33,1.33,1)", 
      msTransform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px, 0px) scale3d(1.33,1.33,1)" });
 setTimeout(function(){
   $(title)
    .css({"transition" : "all 0.7s", 
         "-webkit-transition" : "all 0.7s",
         "-moz-transition" : "all 0.7s",
         "-o-transition" : "all 0.7s"}
        );
 }, 300);
  $(window).scroll(function(){
       requestAnimationFrame(function(){
         lastScrollTop = scrolling(lastScrollTop)});
  });
});
```

Any idea? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem that started when I updated my Chrome to version 41 on Mac (I haven't yet tested anywhere else). I have an absolute positioned element that I update on scroll, and it used to be smooth before updating Chrome but now it's laggy. It's fine in Firefox and Safari so I guess it's a problem with that version of Chrome, at least on Mac.

Comment: hope you're right, I've not found any solution yet :/

Comment: Hi @dghez have you been any lucky so far? In 2022 the problem seems to persist.

Comment: Same problem here. Translation on scroll is laggy on 2021 MacBook Pro 14. Really looking forward for a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Time between frames doesn't matter if computer isn't able to provide acceptable performance. <s>`translate3d` is expensive, try to use normal `translate` (without z-axis).</s>
Also if scale is static (always 1.33) remove it and change other styles like font-size.

**EDIT:**

You did a big mess...
`var title = $("h1");` - duplicates

`$(title)` - for what? it is jQuery object

`var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
var st = $(window).scrollTop();` - the same value in two variables!

`$(window).scroll(function(){
window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){` - doesn't make any sense

`var posTitle = $("h1").offset().top;` - use `title` instead creating new object

Optimized code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var title = $("h1");
    var win = $(window);
    var htmlbody = $('html,body');

    var vh = win.height() - 300;
    var moveY = -(title.offset().top - 300);
    var moveX = -(title.offset().left - 150);

    var lastScrollTop = 0;

    title.css({
            transform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px,0px) scale(1.33)", 
            WebkitTransform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px,0px) scale(1.33)", 
            MozTransform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px,0px) scale(1.33)", 
            msTransform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px,0px) scale(1.33)"
        });
    title.css({
            "transition" : "all 0.8s", 
            "-webkit-transition" : "all 0.8s",
            "-moz-transition" : "all 0.8s",
            "-o-transition" : "all 0.8s"
        });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrolled = win.scrollTop();

        if( htmlbody.is(':animated') )
            return (lastScrollTop = scrolled); // drop


        /* Not needed, but with resizing can be helpful
        var vh = win.height() - 300;
        var moveY = -(title.offset().top - 300);
        var moveX = -(title.offset().left - 150);
        //*/
        /* SCROLL DOWN*/
        console.log("sono il cicli con ST= " + scrolled + ",lastScrollTop= " + lastScrollTop + ", scrolled= " + scrolled + ", vh " + vh );
        if (scrolled > lastScrollTop && scrolled < vh){
            console.log( "scendo" );
            htmlbody.stop().animate({scrollTop : vh}, 700);
            title.css({
                    transform: "translate3d(0px,0px,0px)",
                    WebkitTransform: "translate3d(0px,0px,0px)",
                    MozTransform: "translate3d(0px,0px,0px)",
                    msTransform: "translate3d(0px,0px,0px)"
                });
            title.removeClass("opening");
        }
        /* SCROLL UP*/
        else if(scrolled < vh){
            console.log( "Arrampico" );
            htmlbody.stop().animate({scrollTop : 0}, 700);
            title.css({
                    transform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px,0px) scale(1.33)", 
                    WebkitTransform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px,0px) scale(1.33)", 
                    MozTransform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px,0px) scale(1.33)", 
                    msTransform: "translate3d("+ moveX + "px," + moveY + "px,0px) scale(1.33)"
                });
            title.addClass("opening");
        }
        lastScrollTop = scrolled;
    });
});
```

Comment: Really? I've red everywhere that `translate3d` is better than `translate` because it enable hardware accelerator. BTW, I've altready tried with font size but was worse :(

Comment: Okej, my bad. Check my edit. Small clean up and optimization.

Comment: I tried your version but it's still not smooth :/ I really can't understand where is the problem,